# Split() with regex java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string eg.: 
item 1=$2 item 2=$3 item 3=$4
so of course i cant split on space as i am interested in getting the prices of all the items. So i created a regex

```
    String[] prices = line.split("[a-zA-Z]+\\s[0-9]+\\=\\$");
```

but in the output i am getting 4 elements. One is empty string and rest the values I wanted.I don't understand why 4? I should give three strings What m i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want only the prices (2, 3, 4), the prices with the prefixed currency ($2, $3, $4), or item names as well (item 1 = $2, item 2 = $3, item 3 = $4)?

Comment: I just want to extract the price of each item. Don;t want prefixes with them

Comment: split function splits the string around matches of the given regex, so the first element is all characters before `item 1=$` but because there isn't any it is empty

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks alireza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of assumptions here, but were the goal to find all of the prices in a given line, I would do the following instead of attempting to split the line *per se*.

```
String line = "item 1 = $2 item 2 = $3 item 3 = $4";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\$([\\d]+)");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

> 2
>   3
>   4

Thus, we have just the prices. Now, if the prices can have decimals, etc., the regex needs to be updated.

Such an updated regex might be:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\$([\\d]+[.]?[\\d]*)");
```

And with a modified input of:

```
 String line = "item 1 = $2 item 2 = $3.01 item 3 = $4.53";
```

One gets:

```
2
3.01
4.53
```

Comment: Yes its what i want. Thanks